# How do I create a count plot with multiple columns without the axes being stored in a numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

I'm new to coding and this is my first post. Sorry if it could be worded better!

I'm  taking a free online course, and for one of the projects I have to make a count plot with 2 subplot columns.

I've managed to make a count plot with multiple subplots using the code below, and all of the values are correct.

```
fig = sns.catplot(x = 'variable', hue = 'value', order = ['active', 'alco', 'cholesterol', 'gluc', 'overweight', 'smoke'], col='cardio', data = df_cat, kind = 'count')
```

But because of the way I've done it, the fig.axes is stored in a 2 dimensional array. The only difference between both rows of the array is the title (cardio = 0 or cardio = 1). I'm assuming this is because of the col='cardio'. Does the col argument always cause the fig.axes to be stored in a 2D array? Is there a way around this or do I have to completely change how I'm making my graph?

I'm sure it's not usually a problem, but because of this, when I run my program through the test module, it fails since some of the functions in the test module don't work on numpy.ndarrays.

I pass the test if I change the reference from fig.axes[0] to fig.axes[0,0], but obviously I cant just change the test module to pass.

Comment: FacetGrid has `subplot_kws` (and catplot `facet_kws`) where you could pass `squeeze=True` which should affect the dimensions of the axes. But if seaborn lets you true with this, I don't know.

Comment: You're referring to the shape of `fig.axes` in the question but that was not super easy to figure out. Also, it will still be an ndarray if there are two, you just want it to be ndim=1 instead of ndim=2 (?)

Comment: I've changed the post to make it a little more clear, thankyou! Haven't managed to get `squeeze=True` to work for me yet, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Ok, I don't think (anymore) that there's a way to get through with squeeze. So it seems like catplot and Facetgrid can't be used for this. Wrongly written automatic test? Not up to date with seaborn? Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something. This is just an implementation detail, so it would be nuts to rely on it. If you set col_wrap, then you get an axes ndarray of a different shape.

Reproduced like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns 

# I don't have your data but I have this example
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig = sns.catplot(x='day', hue='sex', col='time', data=tips, kind='count', col_wrap=2)
fig.axes.shape
```

And it has shape (2,) i.e it's 1D. seaborn==0.11.2.

Comment: This fixed it, thankyou! 

By the way this was for project 3 of freecodecamp, I probably should've specified that earlier, whoops! I looked online for how over people did that project, and it seems that they used a bar graph instead, which is why my axes were wrong. 

This seems crazy to me though, is it really better to use a bar graph to make a counts plot when there's a built-in counts plot function, or was this just a weird choice by the designers of the course?